# It is safe to use StatelessWidget when the state changes with a Provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-widget, statelesswidget

I see that the flutter team advise this:

> For example, in Android, this is similar to placing an ImageView with your logo. The logo is not going to change >during runtime, so use a StatelessWidget in Flutter.
> If you want to dynamically change the UI based on data received after making an HTTP call or user interaction then you have to work with StatefulWidget and tell the Flutter framework that the widget’s State has been updated so it can update that widget.
> https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-update-widgets

Im using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), and it lets you use a `ChangeNotifierProvider` to rebuild the widget tree.

If I have a `StatelessWidget` and we use a `ChangeNotifierProvider`, the `build` function is still invoked multiple times when the `ChangeNotifier` notify a change, and the widget rebuilds, which confuses me a lot about the difference between a `StatelessWidget` and a `StatefullWidget`.

1. It is safe to use `StatelessWidget` if we use a `ChangeNotifierProvider` inside of it?
2. Is there any performance gain about using `StatelessWidget` vs `StatefullWidget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little bit confusing but this explanation may help:

Since the `ChangeNotifierProvider` will handle the state, then the parent (your widget) does not need to be `Statefull`, that responsibility goes to the `ChangeNotifierProvider` widget.

Answer (score 2):

"Safe" doesn't apply, since `setState` is a method on `State` class, and since `StatelessWidget` doesn't have one of those, this won't even come up.  And there's no broad sweeping rules about performance.  Try it, and see.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I updated the question, you are totally right, my bad, I rushed into creating the question without thinking about my context, Im using a `Provider`, and it shows a widget that rebuild itself after some changes, it does not use `setState` at all

Comment: And now that you updated question 1, my answer is yes.  There's still no state being held within the StatelessWidget, just a way to transform incoming data to a widget.